# JIRA фильтр задач по параметрам прилинкованных задач

Tags: фильтры, jira

Пытаюсь написать JQL: Найти задачи в прилинкованных задачах к которым исполнитель текущий пользователь. Ну или хотелось хотя бы что то вроде этого:

```
issue in linkedIssues(
     project='Проект' and duedate >  now() AND status not in (Closed, RESOLVED)) 
and assignee = currentUser()
```

По логике этот запрос должен был бы вернуть мои задачи у которых есть ссылки на задачи с проектом "Проект"(не закрытые и не просроченные). Но такой запрос не корректен. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас стоит ScriptRunner, можно сделать так:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee=currentUser() and status!=Готово")
```